# window.createPopup() not supported in IE 11, Fire fox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

the method `createPopup()` is not supported in FF, chrome and IE 11. I am trying to find a good alternative, but before I start coding, I wanna hear if there is someone who has had the same problem, and found a solution that is supported in all major browsers?

Comment: Solution: Do not use popups. Find a way to display the information you would put into the popup on the current page.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Internet Explorer 11, use a `div`,`iframe`, or other element with a relatively high z-index value instead of `createPopup()`.